# Mocking a class with both pure methods and ones with side effects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Suppose we have this interface:

```
public interface IFileSystem
{
    string ReadFile(string filename);
    string CombinePaths(string path1, string path2);
}
```

and the following concrete implementation

```
public class ConcreteFileSystem : IFileSystem
{
    public string CombinePaths(string path1, string path2)
    {
        return path1 + "/" + path2;
    }
}
```

The implementation of `ReadFile` is not important here.

Having a file system instance is very good, since it allows mocking file system calls that have side effects (like `ReadFile`).

We then have a test

```
var mock = new Mock<IFileSystem>();
var fs = mock.Object;

// How do I forward the calls to Mock<IFileSystem>.CombinePaths to ConcreteFileSystem.CombinePaths?

Assert.IsTrue(SomeClass.SomeMethodThatUsesCombinePaths("specificString1"))
```

What is currently being done in my code base is such a code in every test:

```
mock.Setup(f => f.CombinePaths("specificString1", "specificString2"))
    .Returns("specificString1/specificString2");
```

But since tests should test the interface, not the implementation, this seems like a bad approach. Also, when duplicating some test code subtle errors can appear.

---

What I've thought about is

```
mock.Setup(f => f.CombinePaths(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns<string, string>((path1, path2) => new FileSystem().CombinePaths(path1, path2));
```

(maybe this can be shortened with some C# specific syntax).

Such code in the `[SetUp]` section of the tests for every method of `IFilesystem` no longer is dependent on the implementation of `SomeClass.SomeMethodThatUsesCombinePaths`.

My question is, whether this is a good approach or how this approach could be improved. Maybe there is a more fundamental way of doing things differently.

Comment: Mock concrete implementation, setup/override the members with side effects, enable mock with `CallBase` so it knows to call actual members that were not overridden. Note however that the members to be overridden on the implementation need to be virtual or abstract.

Comment: Now my question to you for clarification is what are you actually trying to test here?

Comment: @Nkosi Thank you. I am testing `SomeClass.SomeMethod`. And I need it to write to specific files. And I know the method reads files, and I want to control what is actually "read" there

Comment: @PostSelf Why don't you use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2) in your method under test? "But since tests should test the interface, not the implementation...". Tests should verify specific behavior which you want to verify. Interface doesn't have any behavior, it is just a contract with anything that is being used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using the implementation as is in the test has no side effects then use them.

If members to be used in the implementation have side effects then replace them when testing in isolation to avoid unwanted behavior

Mock concrete implementation, enabling `CallBase` so it knows to call actual members that were not overridden

```
var mock = new Mock<ConcreteFileSystem>() {
    CallBase = true;
};
```

setup/override the members with side effects, .

```
mock.Setup(_ => _.ReadFile(It.IsAny<string>())
    .Returns(string.Empty); //Or what ever content you want
```

Note however that the members to be overridden on the implementation need to be virtual or abstract.

```
public class ConcreteFileSystem : IFileSystem {
    public virtual string CombinePaths(string path1, string path2) {
        return System.IO.Path.Combine(path1, path2);
    }

    public virtual string ReadFile(string path) {
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `virtual` have a negative performance impact as it has in C++?

Comment: I don't understand. How is a virtual function call not any slower than a nonvirtual call? It first has to fetch the correct function to call from the vtable which causes cache misses

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you are mocking `CombinePaths` at all.  Mocking should be done for a reason.  Good reasons are:

- You can not easily bring the depended-on-component (DOC, in this case this is `CombinePaths`) into the desired state for testing.  This does not apply here.
- Does calling the DOC cause any non-derministic behaviour (date/time, randomness, network connections)?  Not the case here.
- Does using the original DOC cause unnacceptably long build / execution times?  Probably not.
- Has the DOC stability (maturity) issues that make the tests unreliable, or, worse, is the DOC not even available yet?  Not the case here.

If all of the above does not apply, why mock?  You don't have to mock everything dogmatically.  For example, you also don't mock standard library math functions like `sin` or `cos`, because they also don't have any of the abovementioned problems.

On a different topic: You say "tests should test the interface, not the implementation".  I disagree: Tests should most importantly find the bugs in your code.  The bugs are in the implementation.  Different implementations of the same functionality will have different bugs.  If implementation was not important, why care about code coverage?  Certainly, having maintainable tests and tests that do not break unnecessarily in case of refactorings are good goals (why testing through the public API is typically a good approach - but not always), but they are secondary goals compared to the goal to find all bugs.

Comment: Yes exaclty, so please tell me the solution :)

Comment: I see, but when you do TDD, then you don't even have an idea about the implementation yet, when you write the tests

Comment: IMO, TDD should be preceded by a design phase where you think about the algorithm.  Or, when implementing a sort function, how would you during TDD come to the conclusion which sorting algorithm to implement?  Or, when implementing a fibonacci function: How does TDD tell you whether to implement an iterative or recursive approach, a closed expression or a lookup table?  These are design decisions that have to be taken independently of TDD.

Comment: It is also important to understand that, when applying TDD, the goal of writing a test is different from the goal of writing a test during unit-testing. As I wrote, the goal of writing tests during unit-testing is to find bugs. During TDD, the goal is to drive the coding: The new test shall demand the next tiny piece of code to be written. Once that piece of code is written, with TDD you move on to the next piece of code. In contrast, with unit-testing, you will typically need more tests for each tiny bit of code.

Comment: Ok true. I am a TDD beginner, but I just finished a project with TDD. I did design everything beforehand, but I did not write the complete algorithm immediately (nor did I know how exactly it would look like), but I just wrote my expected behavior in tests and adjusted the implementation to facilitate that. I did not know the exact function calls, though, until I actually wrote the implementation step